# I am getting weird data as a response

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api, sendmail, nodemailer

I am trying to get some details of mail that I have sended using google-api. I am using messageId that I have received after sending email. I am expection the data to be in json format.

**Here is the Nodejs code for reading sended mail**:

```
app.post("/readMail", async (req, res)=>{
  let messageId = req.body.messageId;

  try {
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      properties.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      properties.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    );
    
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: properties.REFRESH_TOKEN });
    const { token } = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();

    const generateConfig = (url, accessToken) => {
      return {
        method: "get",
        url: url,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken} `,
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
      };
    };

    const url = `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/Abhisek721@gmail.com/messages/${messageId}`;

    const config = generateConfig(url, token);
    const response = await axios(config);

    let data = await response.data;
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
})
```

And This the response:

```
"\u001f\ufffd\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\ufffd\ufffdUmo\ufffd:\u0014\ufffd\ufffd_a\ufffdu\ufffds\u0012^\ufffdN\ufffd\u0006\t/a\ufffd2\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdީr\u0012\ufffd\u0018\ufffd8rLB6\ufffd\ufffd_'P\ufffdݱ\ufffd^]\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd=\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u000e\ufffd\n\ufffd*\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdu\ufffd:\\75\ufffd]C\ufffdrU\ufffdD\ufffd1\ufffdW4(r0\ufffd\ufffdDj\ufffd%\ufffd\ufffdd\ufffd\u0019\ufffd*\ufffd\ufffdR\ufffdD$\ufffd\ufffd(\u0000:!\"\u0014\ufffd8r\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd!\ufffd8\u0004$Nv!"
```

I was expecting to get something like json data.

Comment: Have you tried to console.log some of response properties like `response.headers`, `response.status` and `response.statusText`? Or try `data.toString()`

Comment: Status:  200

Headers:  AxiosHeaders {
  'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
  date: 'Fri, 13 Jan 2023 14:13:30 GMT',
  server: 'ESF',
  'cache-control': 'private',
  'x-xss-protection': '0',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"',
  connection: 'close',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
}

Comment: Maybe the problem is the fact that `res.json` will try to stringify the data before sending. Try `data = JSON.parse(data); console.log(data); res.json(data);`.

Comment: That's not "weird data"  data = The body data of a MIME message part as a base64url encoded string.   One could argue that its a weird format not weird data.   But to each their own.

Comment: @DalmTo But, I tried to convert this base64 into utf-8. Still it wasn't making any sense.

Comment: @Molda I got empty { } when I did JSON.parse(data).

Comment: It looks like Unicode UTF 16, but translates to gibberish. A simple API call like that should return JSON, not any encoded data. Try to log your `accessToken`. What does it look like? It should be a long string starting with `ya29.`. Also, scopes are you using?